# javax.el.ELContext cannot be resolved error when adding FaceletContext jsf maven built

Tags: maven, jsf-2, build, compiler-errors

I have this error when I added those lines in one method of  managed bean : 
I fixed the imports of my project but no result 
I use maven spring jsf and hibernate

here is the error :

```
Unresolved compilation problem: The type javax.el.ELContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

here the lines that causes error :

```
FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
    String formId = (String) faceletContext.getAttribute("hiddenIds");
```

do you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error and resolved the issue by adding el-api-2.2 jar which contains the javax.el.ELContext class. The reason for the above error was javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext class was internally calling the javax.el.ELContext class.

Comment: OP is using Maven. OP just had to set the compiletime Java EE dependency.